# li hover spills out past the ul box

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Why would (on hover) the below, spills out onto past the UL box?

Shouldn't it have a 3px border all around to prevent such happening?

[image]

Here's the markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#container {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#one {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none
}
#two {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}
#menu, ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: default;
    width: 200px;
}
#menu, ul, li {
    padding: 3px;
}
#menu li:hover{
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function showMenu(){
   document.getElementById("one").style.display="block";
 }
 function hideMenu(){
   document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
 }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="one" onclick="hideMenu()">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="two"><img src="images/arrow_double.png" onclick="showMenu()"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main container has `width:200px` :

```
#container {
   width: 200px;
}
```

Then inside you're setting an object with `width:200px` and `padding:3px` it's equal to `206px` total width:

```
#menu, ul {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

You have two solutions:

- One use this property : That makes all `border` and `padding` values to be inside the fixed width.

  ```
   #menu, ul {
     box-sizing:border-box;
   }
  ```
- Two fix your width:

  ```
    #menu, ul {
      width:194px; /*200 - padding for both sides*/
      padding:3px; 
   }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Your div (#container) has a width of 200px and 3px of padding.  Your ul is also 200px wide.  With the padding from the div, the ul spills out of the div.  This is why when you hover the li it goes outside the div box.

Comment: Is not #one is #container who has the width

Answer (score 0):

It's because ul padding:3px
Set it to 0 or change box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

Your container is 200px wide.  The menu is 200px wide + 6px padding (3 for each side).  Set the menu size to 194px wide or remove the menu width entirely.